# How to work with class npm packages in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

so suppose I have an npm package I'd like to use with my project, which was not necessarily made for React. This particular package comes as a Class, which I need to make an object out of.

How could I achieve this in React, when working with class components? Is there a 'standardized way' of doing such a thing?

pseudocode:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {whatever} from 'coolPackage'

class myReactClass extends Component {

 myObject = new whatever()

 render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

export default myReactClass;
```

Comment: LGTM ...........

Comment: Yeah there's no restriction on using third party classes, so if you have a specific problem you should clarify.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, me noob, sorry all for waste time.

There is a problem with the npm package I was trying to use. After checking the error logs again, this time with a lot more care, the problem is not related to the question asked.